# Java POJO to OpenApi Definition

Tags: java, openapi, pojo, converters

I need to add a REST layer to an existing application. The REST interface is being defined by an OpenAPI definition file. The interface is going to be large and should transfer complex and deeply nested datastructures already defined in Java POJO classes. Once the OpenApi definition is complete it should be the source of truth and used to generate Java and Typescript artifacts.

I am looking for a tool that may generate OpenAPI specs from a (top-level) POJO class and help me setup the OpenAPI definitions as fast as possible. BTW I am not allowed to use online tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, but really lots of manual stuff to do, if you can use swagger libraries. If so, you can attach swagger-annotations to your code. After that you can generate your openapi-spec for your Pojos.

Find more at:

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations
- https://swagger.io/tools/open-source/open-source-integrations/

Comment: Thanks Sven, seems exactly what I was looking for. Even though they didnt like my question.